# VimScript - Save specific positions consistently even after buffer changes

Tags: vimscript, cursor, mark, signs

I want to save multiple positions in vimscript, and make sure that they stay at the right place, even after the buffer changes
Here are the solutions I found so far, and why I want something else:

- **Save them in an array**
  If lines are added by the user above the saved positions, they become incorrect (see below GIF, the gray position line `5` is the saved pos)
  [image: demo saving positions]
- **Position marks**
  This works better, but there's a limit of saveable position (52 for the 26 uppercases letters and 26 lowercases), and the user would be able to change them, I don't want that...[image: demo saving marks]
- **Position signs**
  I haven't tried this one yet, but I don't really like it because it sets unnecessary signs on the left side of the editor, and it doesn't save the horizontal position...

Answer (score 2):

What about the new [text-properties](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/textprop.txt.html#text-properties)? They seem to have the *property* (sic) to follow.

> Text properties can be attached to text in a buffer.  They will move with the
>   text: If lines are deleted or inserted the properties move with the text they
>   are attached to.  Also when inserting/deleting text in the line before the
>   text property.

Comment: That looks great.... but I'm using NeoVim, and it's not available yet

Comment: The text "stickiness" you seek had to be coded into Vim 8.2 and is otherwise impossible AFAIK.

Comment: for neovim, try the extended marks